# Jython import of Java package created by Swig fails to link

Tags: java, c++, import, jython, swig

I am working on application that has components written in several languages. I am trying to get functionality that works fine in Java working in Jython. There is some native/C++ functionality that Java access via the JNI and is wrapped by SWIG.

Whenever I try to import all of the classes in the project I get errors that PROJECTJNI cannot be linked. Here is my minimum case to produce:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('PROJECT.jar')
from com.whatever.project import *
```

Here is the error message when this is executed:

```
$ jython Bootstrap.py
"my" variable $jythonHome masks earlier declaration in same scope at /usr/bin/jython line 15.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Bootstrap.py", line 9, in <module>
    from com.whatever.project import *
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.whatever.project.PROJECTJNI.swig_module_init()V
        at com.whatever.project.PROJECTJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
        at com.whatever.project.PROJECTJNI.<clinit>(PROJECTJNI.java:974)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
        at org.python.core.Py.loadAndInitClass(Py.java:909)
        at org.python.core.Py.findClassInternal(Py.java:844)
        at org.python.core.Py.findClass(Py.java:869)
        at org.python.core.packagecache.PackageManager.basicDoDir(PackageManager.java:107)
        at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.doDir(SysPackageManager.java:138)
        at org.python.core.PyJavaPackage.fillDir(PyJavaPackage.java:123)
        at org.python.core.imp.importAll(imp.java:1051)
        at org.python.core.imp.importAll(imp.java:1039)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(Bootstrap.py:9)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(Bootstrap.py)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
        at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
        at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1275)
        at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:235)
        at org.python.util.jython.run(jython.java:247)
        at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:129)

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.whatever.project.PROJECTJNI.swig_module_init()V
```

The line 15 thing shows up on any time we invoke jython, we had been ignoring it.

We can get the classes from the Java Project to work by simply loading them one at a time:

```
com.whatever.project import Class1
com.whatever.project import Class2
...
com.whatever.project import Class50
```

This is highly impractical because even for short python script we might need a dozen classes. Many of them are exceptions that we are catching which have unique types. So anything that robustly handles errors might need a huge number of classes.

As per the [jython documentation](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/ModulesPackages.html#hiding-module-names) I should be able to hide PROJECTJNI so it is not loaded by doing something like this, but I found the docs less than perfectly clear. Here is what I attempted:

```
import com.whatever.project
__all__ = dir(com.whatever.project)
__all__.remove('PROJECTJNI')
from com.whatever.project import *
```

But this fails with errors and still clearly trying to load PROJECTJNI.

I also tried to fix the native executable so it could be linked against correctl. I learned another group using JRuby had no issue including everything, so I decided to check the source and the binary. I found void swig_module_init() in the file Project_wrap.cpp that Swig created. It was hidden behind a macro, but it was there, and objdump confirms:

```
$objdump libPROJECT.so -t |grep PROJECTJNI |grep init
000000000051a900 l     O .data  00000000000009d0              _ZZ59Java_com_whatever_project_PROJECTJNI_swig_1module_1initE7methods
0000000000263f66 g     F .text  00000000000000d1              Java_com_whatever_project_PROJECTJNI_swig_1module_1init
```

Am I doing something wrong with any of my troubleshooting steps? Is the a bug in Jython? Is there a simple Python workaround to make it skip loading PROJECTJNI?

Anything that lets me skip linking this or makes this link correctly will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one of the Java classes, the BinaryLoader, there was a method called void load_binary() that is called in a static section of that class:

```
public class BinaryLoader
{
    static
        { load_binaries(); }

    public static void load_binaries()
    {
        // Deep inside here is a call to actually load the shared library. Using
        load_shared_library_from_jar("PROJECT");
    }
 ... // more details here
 }
```

Our Java code using the native API called this method as the class was loaded. Our JRuby code called this when the class was 'touched', just using the Constant's name, the name of the class, invoked the static section. To clarify here is a sample from our docs and live Ruby scripts that does this:

```
# Tells Jruby to load the Java Interopability layer.
require 'java'

# Loads the PROJECT Java tools.
require 'PROJECT.jar'

# Shorten the PROJECT tool names from their obnoxiously long Java name.
module PROJECT
    include_package "com.whatever.project"
end

# Let Ruby know the BinaryLoader exists and it will have PROJECT load all the system binaries.
PROJECT::BinaryLoader
```

Apparently requiring the JarFile is enough to make all the Native symbols and Java classes available in Ruby and the binary isn't loaded until the last line which is just an expressions that resolves to the name of the class and force the static section to run. The actual method call would have looked like: PROJECT::BinaryLoader.load_binaries

In Jython the static section was never invoked even when calling other static methods on the BinaryLoader class. I forced it to call the method manually by importing the minimum of Java and Native symbols to call the method:

```
# Tells Jython to load the python system Interopability tools.
import sys

# When searching for python symbols, this Java jar should be search also.
sys.path.append('PROJECT.jar')

# Load just enough the have the JVM Know how to load the native PROJECT libraries
from com.whatever.project import PROJECT
from com.whatever.project import BinaryLoader

# Load any native binaries that are required
BinaryLoader.load_binaries()

# After this line is run in any given script then PROJECT can be used.
from com.whatever.project import *
```

Clearly the native binaries were simply not loaded as had been thought. Anything that loaded these would have been an acceptable solution.

This works around Jython not invoking the static section, by doing the work it should have as early as possible. This seems like a bug in Jython, but it might be that guarantees on static load order are not strongly enforced in Java. Either way because this incompatibility we will likely be removing the static section to prevent future Java ad Ruby Devs from adding something that could fail to load in Python.